# Triple stops in Bruch's violin concerto

Tags: chords, violin, double-stops

I've been finding it hard to find a good fingering that lets me play this sequence in Bruch's violin concerto.

[image]

Moreover, I'm finding it hard to actually hit all three strings simultaeneously on a downbow, although I suppose this could be fixed by moving slightly closer to the fingerboard. That being said, even then hitting all three is hard for me (partially since I'm scared of striking too hard with the bow!)

What are the ideal fingerings to use for these chords?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When playing three or four string stops, don't try to play all the strings at once. For a triple stop, you start double on the lower two notes and rotate to the upper two notes during the bow stroke, roughly splitting the duration of the note in half for each double.  On a four note stop you play the bottom two strings, then transition to the top two.

Ideal fingerings for passages on the violin can vary for each musician, depending on their experience and ability. In some arrangements fingering suggestions are provided by the publisher, but musicians may take or leave them depending on their comfort and play style.

Just glancing at the passage, I would probably start in second position with 2nd finger across the GD and use 4th to 3rd down the CB and position shift somewhere around the next bar.

Comment: A nit -- depending on the composer and the style, etc., you may want to emphasize either the first pair or the second pair, or you may want to play the first pair almost as a grace "chord" (note) leading to the upper double-stop.

Comment: Good point Carl, there are many ways to approach the stops. I start students out with an even split as a basic technique builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing down. The middle string will, under enough pressure, sink down. Worked for me in Kreisler’s praeludium and allegro.